# three.js Collada loader doesn't work inside ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, three.js, collada

I am currently working on a project in which I am using a Collada 3D renderer and three.js. I use the Collada loader in a html page which works perfectly.

I wanted to implement this page inside a ASP.NET (aspx) in order to use it with a SQL server database. But when I copy&paste the content of the page inside an .aspx page and execute the project from the Visual basic, the renderer doesn't work.
By the way, when I use other three.js examples which don't use Collada files they work properly.
Could someone help me resolve this problem ?